How does a frisbee compare to disc golf discs
I have a frisbee that I tried out on a disc golf course. the flight was different from my discs. So, I actually have two questions: is a frisbee allowed? more importantly, does anyone know how a frisbee compare to discs as far as flight numbers?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The main difference is in the equipment itself.

The biggest difference between frisbees and discs lies in the equipment itself. Frisbees are typically made of stiff plastic designed for recreational use. When you think of a frisbee, you likely consider it a fun activity to pass back and forth between friends. On the other hand, disc golf discs are built for distance and control.

(Bolding mine, unable to find a non-corporate source.)
Another thing I found was this interesting quote:

...golf discs are made from a pliable plastic that’s easier to grip, especially when you’re aiming for that long shot. Even though frisbees and golf discs might weigh roughly the same... golf discs feel heftier due to their dense composition.

(Once again, bolding mine. This source had a PDGA link that proved to be of no use.)
Quick recap, golf discs are built for distance and control, while most frisbees you buy at a store are made to play casual throw-and-catch games, but they weigh roughly the same, despite golf discs feeling heavier because of their density. Frisbees not used for casual throw and catch are, for example, Ultimate. (Thanks, @PhillipKendall) Others, feel free to comment to add anything.

That depends on your frisbees; frisbees for Ultimate are not designed for a "casual throw-and-catch game".

@PhilipKendall Edited. Thanks.
